# plotly title_side position not working properly

Tags: python, plotly, legend, centering, legend-properties

I'm greenhand with Python plots but I was trying to do a PCA for different human populations; while I'm still working on the actual data, the main issue I'm having with visualizations in Python, as opposed to `R`, is that doesn't make things very easy...

Specifically, I spent some time figuring out how to set the layout of my plot but I can't get the *legend title* to show in the middle of the legend itself.

Supposedly, there is an option in `title_side` which should do so; however, instead, it corrupts the plot legend. If anyone has any experience with this, any help would be much appreciated. Below the code for plotting and the PCA plot.

```
fig = px.scatter(pca, x='PC1', y='PC2', color='#LOC', template="seaborn")

fig.update_layout(legend=dict(
    title="<i> metapopulation <i>",
    title_side="top",
    orientation="h",
    entrywidthmode='fraction',
    entrywidth=.2,
    x=.5),
    autosize=False,
    height=800,
    width=800
)

fig.update_xaxes(title_text = f"PC1 ( {pve.at[pve.index[0], 0]} %)",
                 range=(-0.05, 0.2),
                 constrain='domain')
fig.update_yaxes(title_text = f"PC2 ( {pve.at[pve.index[1], 0]} %)",
                 scaleanchor="x",
                 scaleratio=1)

fig.show()
```

**EDIT** for @Naren Murali
This is what I mean by corrupted legend and figure too, I just realized the use of a `dict` somehow shifts the whole scatter plot...
[image]

**Original Image**
[image]

Comment: I have identified your issue using the example in the [reference](https://plotly.com/python/line-and-scatter/#setting-size-and-color-with-column-names). You can achieve this by modifying the following. `fig.update_layout(legend=dict(title=dict(text="<i> metapopulation <i>",side="top center"),orientation="h",entrywidthmode='fraction',entrywidth=.2,x=.2
),autosize=False,height=800,width=800)` The legend is centered at the top and the start of the legend is set manually. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vdoix.png) is the resulting output figure.

Comment: @r-beginners thanks a lot it seems to be the correct approach as Naren Murali was suggesting as well. However, using exactly that code I simply get a squished legend... see edit above. I'm using VS Code could that be the issue at this point?

Comment: I ran it in vscode and checked the output in Microsoft Edge, but the legend did not overlap. My execution environment is the latest version of plolty, vscode, and Microsoft Edge respectively.

Comment: @r-beginners same here I'm up-to-date with all tools (I just double-checked the version of `plotly` yesterday) and my VS Code is up to date. One thing bothering me was that although `pip` shows `plotly v5.18.0` my VS Code tells me that for plotting it used `Plotly.js v.2.20.0`... Am I importing `plotly` correctly? This is my command: `import plotly.express as px`

Answer (score 1):

Could you try changing  `title` to  a dict containing two properties `text` and `side`. Since we are using legend as a `dict` then we cannot use `legend_title_side` since its not a part of the root dict of `fig.update_layout`

As per the docs:

### [side](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/#layout-legend-title-side)

> Code: fig.update_layout(legend_title_side=<VALUE>)
>
> #### Type: enumerated , one of ( "top" | "left" | "top left" | "top center" | "top right" )
>
> Determines the location of legend's title with respect
> to the legend items. Defaulted to "top" with `orientation` is "h".
> Defaulted to "left" with `orientation` is "v". The "top left" options
> could be used to expand top center and top right are for horizontal
> alignment legend area in both x and y sides.

---

### [text](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/#layout-legend-title-text)

> Code: fig.update_layout(legend_title_text=)
>
> #### Type: string
>
> Default: "" Sets the title of the legend.

```
fig.update_layout(legend=dict(
    title=dict(
        text="<i> metapopulation </i>",
        side="top center"
    ),
    orientation="h",
    entrywidthmode='fraction',
    entrywidth=.2,
    x=.5),
    autosize=False,
    height=800,
    width=800
)
```

Comment: indeed thanks for the explanation it makes perfect sense. However, upon following up with the fixes you suggested I ended up with the same corrupted legend I was having simply using the "top center" key... I will edit the original message to show what happens. Let me know whether there is a solution to this

Comment: @Matteo one small change we need to add closing tag like `</i>` updated my answer!

Comment: Thanks a lot for these fixes! This fixes the shifted scatter plot issue, but unfortunately the legend still appears as in the edited plot...